# R is throwing errors for semPlot and semPath

Tags: r, semplot

**Update: This problem seems to be unique to Mac**

The installation of semPlot seems to go fine, but when I call the library, it throws an error about package 'glasso' not found. When I try to use semPath, it says the function is not found.

Have restarted RStudio countless times. R is up to date as is my computer (MacOS Mojave version 10.14.6).

I tried the solution in an earlier post about restarting RStudio and then installing again and installing XML as well and that did not work either. I included the dependencies argument to make sure it was completely installed although I don't think that has anything to do with it. Code is below including the session info.

```
install.packages("semPlot", dependencies = TRUE)
library(semPlot)
semPaths(aa.cfa.fitted)
sessionInfo()
```

Output is as follows:

```
> install.packages("semPlot", dependencies = TRUE)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.6/semPlot_1.1.2.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 344192 bytes (336 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 336 KB


The downloaded binary packages are in
    /var/folders/9b/fg1p3n5j3_d8wvtpwz1_tvx00000gn/T//RtmpyOIMa0/downloaded_packages
> library(semPlot)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘semPlot’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 there is no package called ‘glasso’
> semPaths(aa.cfa.fitted)
Error in semPaths(aa.cfa.fitted) : could not find function "semPaths"
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Mojave 10.14.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

Random number generation:
 RNG:     Mersenne-Twister 
 Normal:  Inversion 
 Sample:  Rounding 

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

other attached packages:
[1] GPArotation_2014.11-1 nFactors_2.3.3.1     
[3] lattice_0.20-38       boot_1.3-23          
[5] MASS_7.3-51.4         psych_1.8.12         
[7] lavaan_0.6-5         

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] splines_3.6.1       carData_3.0-2       Formula_1.2-3      
 [4] BDgraph_2.61        stats4_3.6.1        latticeExtra_0.6-28
 [7] lisrelToR_0.1.4     pbivnorm_0.6.0      pillar_1.4.2       
[10] backports_1.1.4     digest_0.6.21       RColorBrewer_1.1-2 
[13] checkmate_1.9.4     minqa_1.2.4         colorspace_1.4-1   
[16] htmltools_0.3.6     Matrix_1.2-17       plyr_1.8.4         
[19] XML_3.98-1.20       pkgconfig_2.0.3     xtable_1.8-4       
[22] corpcor_1.6.9       scales_1.0.0        jpeg_0.1-8         
[25] openxlsx_4.1.0.1    fdrtool_1.2.15      lme4_1.1-21        
[28] arm_1.10-1          tibble_2.1.3        htmlTable_1.13.2   
[31] rockchalk_1.8.144   ggplot2_3.2.1       nnet_7.3-12        
[34] lazyeval_0.2.2      mnormt_1.5-5        magrittr_1.5       
[37] survival_2.44-1.1   crayon_1.3.4        kutils_1.69        
[40] nlme_3.1-141        foreign_0.8-72      truncnorm_1.0-8    
[43] regsem_1.3.9        data.table_1.12.2   tools_3.6.1        
[46] stringr_1.4.0       munsell_0.5.0       cluster_2.1.0      
[49] zip_2.0.4           compiler_3.6.1      sem_3.1-9          
[52] rlang_0.4.0         grid_3.6.1          nloptr_1.2.1       
[55] rstudioapi_0.10     htmlwidgets_1.3     igraph_1.2.4.1     
[58] Rsolnp_1.16         base64enc_0.1-3     mi_1.0             
[61] gtable_0.3.0        abind_1.4-5         reshape2_1.4.3     
[64] gridExtra_2.3       knitr_1.25          Hmisc_4.2-0        
[67] stringi_1.4.3       matrixcalc_1.0-3    parallel_3.6.1     
[70] Rcpp_1.0.2          rpart_4.1-15        acepack_1.4.1      
[73] png_0.1-7           xfun_0.10           coda_0.19-3
```

Answer (score 0):

What about installing [glasso](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glasso/index.html) first?

```
install.packages("glasso")
install.packages("semPlot")
```

I assume that this should solve it (no MacOS around to test, sorry).